# HTML Compression (apache)

Tags: html, performance, apache, compression

In my web site the HTML pages are dynamically created using JSP's that are hosted on IBM Application server and passed back to the browser through Apache web server. DEFLATE module has been enabled on Apache to compress the HTML's that are generated. The HTML's source shows many white spaces after it is delivered on the browser and that makes me think if the web server compression is taking effect.

How can I validate if the compression is taking effect? The request header shows Accept-encoding as 'gzip/deflate' while the response shows content encoding as 'gzip'.

Secondly, are there any filters available to remove the white spaces/ comments etc from the HTML that is generated at run time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have knowledge for a filter that removes white spaces and comments. If you find one share ti with us.
For the other part of your question.
The Request Header just informs your web server that the browser knows how to handle compressed content either it is compressed with gzip or it is compress with deflate.
The Respones from your web server tell us that he served a filed that is compressed using gzip. So yes, this particullary response returned a file that is compressed with gzip.